# Authenticating the cobrand

Tags: yodlee

I created a new developer account and I am having a problem authenticating with the REST API.

```
POST https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/authenticate/coblogin

{ cobrandLogin: 'sbCob*****',
  cobrandPassword: '**********' }
```

the system responds with:

```
{ Error: [ { errorDetail: 'Internal Core Error has occurred' } ] }
```

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I am getting the same response. Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Ranvijay check my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am testing the API with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and apparently I need to send the params with `x-www-form-urlencoded` to make it work. Using the default `form-data` lead to the above mentioned error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was solved by changing the content-type as per http://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference

```
require 'rest-client'
module Yodlee

    def self.login_to_yodlee
        site = self.site_resource

        login_hash = {
            cobrandLogin: 'yourlogin',
            cobrandPassword: 'yourpassword'

        }
        begin
            response = site["/authenticate/coblogin"].post login_hash, :'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            puts response
        rescue RestClient::ResourceNotFound => ex
            raise Exception.new(ex.response)
        rescue Exception => ex
            raise Exception.new(ex)
        end
    end

    def self.site_resource
        RestClient::Resource.new('https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0')
    end

end

Yodlee.login_to_yodlee
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this error comes when you do not provide the input parameter's name correctly; while in this mentioned code above I could see that both of them are correct. I'd suggest you to please double check the input parameter name(case sensitive) as well properly. And just to mention you should be sending it as two different parameters i.e., 'cobrandLogin' and cobrandPassword.